# When opening VBA Editor (Alt+F11) in Excel, which module loads first?

Tags: vba, module, editor, default

I have 3 Modules in the following order, with the following names:
CodeMain
DeltaKommCode
Testing

Everytime I open the VBA Editor after a fresh start of Excel (Alt+F11), it shows the Testing Module. Why is that? Why doesn't it show the first module in alphabetical or chronological order, or what is the logic behind which module appears first?

Comment: The IDE active window. For the first time, it opens the active sheet module...

Comment: What does that mean? None of my 3 modules are associated to any sheets. They are simply under Modules.

Comment: Excel does not care about your wish, from this point of view. Even if you do not use them, sheet modules exist. One for each worksheet in the workbook. If you have an active window in IDE, this one will take focus after pressing Alt + F11. If not, you will see the empty active sheet module... But, what would you like to accomplish clarifying this aspect?

Comment: I see now that it does select the active sheet in the VBAProject like you say. But in the view, it's showing the "Testing" module. So I guess that means I have an "active window in IDE". (What does that mean?) What I still don't understand is why it picks the "Testing" module and not one of the other two modules? What I'm trying to accomplish is getting it to show my chronologically and alphabetically first module called "CodeMain". It would just be more convenient for me if that shows first, because it saves a step of clicking on the Module every time I want to edit it, which is often.